# Pgfplot xlabel is not centered

Tags: pgfplots

I created a plot using pgfplot package, but my xlabel is not centered and looks like this (xlabel is "dimenze vektoru")[image]

my code:

```
  \begin{figure} % <---
    \centering % <---
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={dimenze vektoru},
    ylabel={syntaktická úspěšnost [\%]},
    xmin=0, xmax=1000,
    ymin=30, ymax=60,
    xtick={},
    ytick={},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    xscale=1.5,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (50, 34.37)(100, 47.06)(200,55.59)(300,57.43)(500,53.56)(760,51.71)(1000,48.85)
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Klesající syntaktická úspěšnost při zvyšující se rychlosti učení}
\label{fig:graph2}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi, please post a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: It is because of the `xscale=1.5`. Instead use `height` and `width` keys to adjust the size